# Is there a way to set non-style attributes in a website's css file?

Tags: css

Suppose I want all `<textarea>s` to have some property, but I don't want to modify all pages individually. The website uses a common `.css` file for all pages.

If it's a change of fonts, padding, paragraph colouring, etc, it's easy, I modify the site `.css` file and all pages inherit.

But what about adding attribs like `onkeydown="STRING"` *(sorry, not onclick)* or `autocomplete="off"` - can I do that in any way through the .css file, or do I have no choice but hard-coding in each textarea or adding an onload script to every page that has text area elements?

Comment: `autocomplete` affects behaviour, not style, so it would make no sense to have them in the CSS. `onclick` belongs in a JS file anyway.

Comment: It isn't ideal, I agree. But the situation is different because I don't control the codebase itself. It's a website package and I want to minimise any page changes. Every change has to be made any time there's a new version. One change is fine, hundreds isn't. If I change the css file, it's one file and inherits. I'd prefer that, to having to do a find/replace across the entire codebase each time it's updated. Not ideal but I'm looking for simple solutions. If it's at all possible via CSS (ideal or not), I'd prefer doing it that way. Autocomplete slows it badly on large texts.

Comment: Updating is usually a process in itself anyway, I don't think adding a global-search-and-edit step to the process is a bad thing. How often do updates happen anyway?

Comment: 2-3 times a year, there's no "process" beyond click one button once (nice eh? :) ). But I'm using multiple instances, and it's a matter of elegance as well. One file change - even not ideal - is still better than hundreds, given that it's a custom mod/code change. Also simpler and less risk of missing anything (textareas added dynamically or constructed serverside, so I have to modify the PHP/Python files creating it as well?)

Comment: onkeydown not onclick, sorry

Answer (score 1):

From my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565685/can-we-specify-custom-data-attribute-values-in-css/36565775#36565775):

> CSS is not HTML. You cannot set or change the value of an HTML attribute using CSS.
>
> *[...]*
>
> If you're trying to assign metadata to a class name which then applies to all elements with that class name, that's (again) completely outside of the purview of CSS, and simply not possible in HTML. The only way to assign metadata to an element is to specify it as an attribute on that element. (You can move the attribute declarations to a script if you don't want to specify the attributes on every instance of that class within the markup, but at the end of the day the script still has to populate each element's dataset with those values. Depending on your needs, though, this may be sufficient.)

You don't need to add an onclick handler to every page that contains textareas. You can put the handler in a script and link to that script in every page, just as you would a stylesheet. If you mean you want to do this from the stylesheet alone without modifying the pages or introducing another external file, then the point about CSS not being HTML, or JavaScript for that matter, remains.

If that's still not an option, I'm afraid there are no alternatives. There certainly aren't any for the `autocomplete` attribute.

Comment: How would I do that - can you add an example to your answer? The exact situation of the event is that I want to be able to use tabs as tabs in the textarea (when it includes indends, code, etc). But at the moment it's not trapped, it just moves fields, so I have to type a tab in a text editor and copy-paste (urghhhhh!). I'm using onkeydown (not onclick, sorry!) to handle the \x09 key and do this. It's short self contained one-line code. Any way to add it to all text areas without modifying all the pages would be good.