# Separate each character with a dot in css

Tags: html, css, angular

How can you transform **abc** to **a. b. c.** in pure css.

Only if this is not posible how can you achieve this than in angular (typescript).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I replace text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896402/how-can-i-replace-text-with-css)

Comment: Short answer. no it is not: [Can we specify custom data attribute values in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565685/can-we-specify-custom-data-attribute-values-in-css)

Comment: Do you need a space after the last character?

Answer (score 3):

With typescript it's easy

```js
"abc".split('').join('. ') + "."
```

you can make a pipe if you need to reuse this function in several places.

With CSS, I don't know how it is possible. I'm curious to know if there is a CSS solution. I suppose no (:

Comment: It won't add dot and space after last char

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the dom:

You can place a span around each character and then use the ::after pseudo-element to add the periods after each one.

It would look something like:

```
span::after{
content:"."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't write CSS solution to do that in functional way. You can replace that in way that @MaxiGui placed in a comment. If you want to achieve that in typescript (or javascript) you can use this code:

```
const txt = 'abc';
const transformedTxt = `${txt.split('').join('. ')}.`;
```